# Почему не передаётся переменная?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

```
function func(id){
var elem=document.getElementById(id);
var elem_value=$(elem).val();
jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"ajax/edit.php",data:{id:elem_value}});}

$('#elem').focus(function(){func('elem');});
```

Comment: Передается: http://jsfiddle.net/G8CaC/

Comment: зачем вам id там ? 

    function func(e){
       var elem=$(this);
       var elem_value=$(elem).val();
       jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"ajax/edit.php",data:{id:elem_value}});} 
    }
    $('#elem').focus(func);

Comment: Вангую, что ТС имел в виду, почему не передается значение переменной `id` в выражение `data:{id:elem_value}}`

Исходя из названий, он, как мне кажется, хочет отправлять в `ajax/edit.php` пару идентифкатор_поля-значение.

Если моя гипотеза верна, то можно реализовать это как-то так:


    function func(id){
      var elem=document.getElementById(id);
      var elem_value=$(elem).val();
      var data = {};
      date[id] = elem_value;
      jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"ajax/edit.php",data: data});}

    $('#elem').focus(function(){func('elem');});

Comment: @Nofate если вопрос в этом, то не передается, потому-что он на focus посылает данные а не на blur, значение передается в той конструкции нормально: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SRawa/

Comment: @eicto, вы кажется не поняли мою мысль. Я о том, что имея

    <div id="#elem">123</div>

ТС хочет отправить на сервер `{ 'elem': '123' }`, а не `{ 'id' : '123'}`. Т.е. заменить `id` на собственно `id` )

Возможно, я не прав, и что-то додумываю. Но больше тут проблему с передачей переменной родить негде.

Comment: ну если так.... :) lol.

Answer (score 1):

Вот так с помощью jquery получаем содержимое элемента div:

```
var element_val = $('div#elem').html();
```

Вот так инпута:

```
var element_val = $('input[name="name"]').val();
```

Comment: у инпута тоже может быть id